# Overwriting a file in PySpark, without affecting others

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Overwriting a file in PySpark, without affecting others.

I need to save a dataframe as a parquet file. If a directory for a given file already exists, I need to overwrite it, but upper subdirectories should not be ovewritten.

Example:

```
root/2021/12/01/file1.parquet
root/2021/12/02/file2.parquet
root/2021/12/03/file3.parquet
```

If /2021/12/01/file1.parquet is being re-created (or overwritten), the other two files in the root remain as-is. Path /2021/12 is part of the partition structure of these files. Hence, .mode("overwrite") will overwrite the other two files as file1 is being re-created.

How can this be accomplished in PySpark?

Answer (score -1):

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/tmp/output/people.parquet")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I am already well aware of this option, but it does not help, which is why I am here. When the first file in my example is overwritten, the other two files disappear, since they share the same path: /2021/12. This path is part of the partition structure for these files.

Comment: for me its not deleting the other two files. i tried ur code